# Is there any open source or free graphic/reports/charts framework for windows forms?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, graphics, charts

Are there any open source or free graphic/reports/charts framework for windows forms?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've heard good things about zedgraph - http://sourceforge.net/projects/zedgraph/

Answer (score 4):

You can get the [Microsoft Chart Controls](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyId=130F7986-BF49-4FE5-9CA8-910AE6EA442C&displaylang=en) for .NET that they released a while ago. It is fairly easy to use but for one reason or another not widely known.

Answer (score 1):

would the [MS charting library](http://archive.msdn.microsoft.com/mschart) suffice? It supports both web and winforms usage...